# How to print a separator line at an specific location in the results of a `#+BEGIN_SRC` block whose language is C++?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, c++

## The context

In `#+BEGIN_SRC` blocks whose language is Python, I can show a separator line in the table that shows the results by using `None` (see example below)

```
#+begin_src python :results output table
print([['Number', 'Number * 10'], None, [1, 10], [2, 20]])
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| Number | Number * 10 |
|--------+-------------|
|      1 |          10 |
|      2 |          20 |
```

## The question

I wonder how I can get that same behavior in `#+BEGIN_SRC` blocks whose language is C++ (see below)

```
#+begin_src cpp :results output table
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Number" << '\t' << "Number * 10" <<  std::endl
            << 1 << '\t' << 10 << std::endl
            << 2 << '\t' << 20 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| Number | Number * 10 |
|      1 |          10 |
|      2 |          20 |
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `None -> hline` translation in a python list seems to be implemented specifically in `ob-python.el` and I don't see a similar hack in `ob-C.el`.

Comment: BTW, the python behavior is available in elisp as well, translating the symbol `hline` in a list to a separator in the tabel output: ```#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq tbl '(("a" "b" "c") hline (1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
tbl
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| a | b | c |
|---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
``` The formatting is atrocious, but I don't think I can do any better in a comment.